# obtain the String matching only the immediate predecessor

Tags: javascript, java, regex

I have the below String

`"8 IN, Ball Valve, Trunnion, Gen manu, CL 900, BW, Body LTCS, Metal Seat, Gear Operated, Trim Alloy 825, Full Bore, NACE MR 0175/ISO 15156 -with extended pup-piece as pipe schedule. VBFW 91Z08"`

I need to obtain the string **Gen Manu** thats available before the , CL and After the previous comma (the comma after Trunnion in this case). I have tried below so far

`(?=\,).(?=.\w).*.(?=\,.CL)`

I am unable to perform a partial match

below is where I saved my work, any help regarding this is greatly appreciated

https://regexr.com/59deb

thanks

Comment: Java or JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex: `(?<=, )[^,]+(?=, CL)`

`(?<=, )` before the match there is a comma followed by space.

`[^,]+` the match is at least one character excluding any commas.

`(?=, CL)` match should be followed by the string ", CL"

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/tMlQby/1